# Hide div after showing it with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, show-hide

I'm using javascript to show a hidden div by clicking a button. After the div is displayed, I want to be able to click the button again and hide the div, and so on...

Here is my javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function showDiv() {
   document.getElementById('dropdownText').style.display = "block";
}
</script>
```

This is the button:

```
<input type="button" name="answer" value="+" onclick="showDiv()" />
```

This is the hidden div:

```
<div id="dropdownText" style="display:none;">
   This is the dropdown text.
</div>
```

Comment: And your question is...? And are you really using jQuery?

Comment: So what have you tried and where did you get stuck?

Comment: How about `if (...style.display=='block') ...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can e.g. bind specified class to the element and just toggle it.

```js
function showDiv() {
   document.getElementById('dropdownText').classList.toggle("hidden");
}
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<input type="button" name="answer" value="+" onclick="showDiv()" />
This is the hidden div:

<div id="dropdownText" class='hidden'>
   This is the dropdown text.
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you tagged this question with jQuery as well, so I guess you could use the .toggle function, like this -

```
$('#answer').click(function() {
    $('#dropdownText').toggle();
}
```

If you want to stick up with javascript only, your showDiv() function should look like this -

```
function showDiv() {
     let text = document.getElementById('dropdownText');
     if (text.style.display === 'none') {
       text.style.display = 'block';
    } 
    else {
    text.style.display = 'none';
    }
}
```

You should capture the current style every time a button is clicked, since you want to 'toggle' it back to the opposite state.

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to do this:

```js
const drop = document.getElementById('dropdownText')

const toggleDropdown = _ => {
   const cl = drop.classList
   cl.contains('hide')?cl.remove('hide'):cl.add('hide')
}
```

```css
#dropdownText.hide {display:none}


/* DropDown Styles for this demo */ 
#dropdownText {width: 10em; height: 4em; background: green}
```

```html
<button onclick='toggleDropdown()'>Toggle Div</button>
<div id='dropdownText'></div>
```

***Note:*** Click `Run Code Snippet` to see the code in action.

---

The way it works is by detecting if it has the hide class and based on that, toggle that class.

The actual hiding and showing is done via CSS!

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="dropdownText" style="display:none">
This is the dropdown text.
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

function showDiv() {
    var x = document.getElementById('dropdownText');
    if (x.style.display === 'none') {
        x.style.display = 'block';
    } else {
    x.style.display = 'none';
    }
}
</script>
```